# Updating row in SQLite database creates a duplicate row

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database in my Android app with 4 default entries. When I try to update one row in the database, it updates it properly, but it also creates a duplicate of the original row and gives it a new ID.

This database only has a single column, plus its ID column, but I have a different database with multiple columns and the update works fine for that/no duplicates, but not for this one.

The original 4 default are Work, Health, Family, and Spiritual with IDs of 1, 2, 3, and 4, respectively. After the update, it's Work 2.0, Health, Family, Spiritual, and Work, with IDs of 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5.

Here is my update method in my ContentProvider:

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    String tableName;
    int uriNum = uriMatcher.match(uri);

    switch (uriNum) {
        //Case 1 is for the entire Goals table
        case 1:
            break;

        //Case 2 is for a specific row in the Goals table
        case 2:
            if (selection != null) {
                selection = selection + "_ID = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            }
            else {
                selection = "_ID = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            }
            break;

        //Case 3 is for the entire Categories table
        case 3:
            break;

        //Case 4 is for a specific row in the Categories table
        case 4:
            if (selection != null) {
                selection = selection + "_ID = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            }
            else {
                selection = "_ID = " + uri.getLastPathSegment();
            }
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI not found.");
    }

    if(uriNum == 1 || uriNum == 2) {
        tableName = GoalsContract.Goals.TABLE_NAME;
    }
    else {
        tableName = CategoriesContract.Categories.TABLE_NAME;
    }

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbHelper.onCreate(db);

    Log.d(TAG,
            tableName + "\n" +
            selection + "\n"
    );

    int count = db.update(tableName, values, selection, selectionArgs);

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return count;
}
```

And the calling code:

```
    ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
    updatedValues.put(CategoriesContract.Categories.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, "Work 2.0");

    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CategoriesContract.Categories.CONTENT_URI, 1);

    int count = getContentResolver().update(uri, updatedValues, null, null);
```

**EDIT:**

The dbHelper class:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(GoalsContract.Goals.SQL_CREATE_GOALS);
    db.execSQL(CategoriesContract.Categories.SQL_CREATE_CATEGORIES);

    //TODO Do on a different thread
    addDefaultData(db);
}

private void addDefaultData(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String[] defaultCategories = {"Work", "Health", "Family", "Spiritual"};

    for(int x = 0; x < defaultCategories.length; x++) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CategoriesContract.Categories.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, defaultCategories[x]);
        db.insert(CategoriesContract.Categories.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    }
}
```

And the actual SQL to create the table:

```
    static final String SQL_CREATE_CATEGORIES =
     "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
     _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
     COLUMN_NAME_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);" ;
```

Comment: How did you create the database? 
 Please make sure to include all the steps, it could be the row auto id issue, not sure yet until I see how you create the table. Thanks

Comment: Added the dbHelper class and the SQL it executes.

Comment: Checking, trying to get it working in the env.
BTw I already see something you may want to use it.
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,

Comment: Can you try to remove UNIQUE? I think PRIMARY and UNIQUE are creating this issue. Let me know if it works. and of course put autoincrement

Comment: Removing UNIQUE without using AUTOINCREMENT works. I didn't use AUTOINCREMENT intentionally because the ID column comes from BaseColumns and that does its own thing. Is there any way to check to make sure duplicate values don't get added, now that the UNIQUE modifier is gone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample SQLiteDatabase `update` method:

```
db.update(TABLE_NAME, ContentValues, KEY_COLUMN_NAME + " = ? ", new String[]{String.valueOf(COLUMN_VALUE)})
```

**Modify your `update()` method as below:**

```
@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    String tableName;
    int uriNum = uriMatcher.match(uri);

    switch (uriNum) {
        //Case 1 is for the entire Goals table
        case 1:
            break;

        //Case 2 is for a specific row in the Goals table
        case 2:
            if (selection != null) {
                selection = selection + "_ID = ? ";
            }
            else {
                selection = "_ID = ? ";
            }
            break;

        //Case 3 is for the entire Categories table
        case 3:
            break;

        //Case 4 is for a specific row in the Categories table
        case 4:
            if (selection != null) {
                selection = selection + "_ID = ? ";
            }
            else {
                selection = "_ID = ? ";
            }
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("URI not found.");
    }

    if(uriNum == 1 || uriNum == 2) {
        tableName = GoalsContract.Goals.TABLE_NAME;
    }
    else {
        tableName = CategoriesContract.Categories.TABLE_NAME;
    }

    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbHelper.onCreate(db);

    Log.d(TAG, tableName + "\n" + selection + "\n");

    int count = db.update(tableName, values, selection, selectionArgs);

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

    return count;
}
```

**Call `update()` method as below:**

```
ContentValues updatedValues = new ContentValues();
updatedValues.put(CategoriesContract.Categories.COLUMN_NAME_NAME, "Work 2.0");

Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CategoriesContract.Categories.CONTENT_URI, 1);

int count = getContentResolver().update(uri, updatedValues, null, new String[]{String.valueOf(1));
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I want to be able to update a single row by just passing in the URI and the values. Removing the unique constraint from the name column fixed it.

Comment: You can make selectionArgs from update method as below: int count = db.update(tableName, values, selection, new String[]{String.valueOf(uri.getLastPathSegment())});